# swift: how to show the vertical indicator of scrollView?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show vertical indicator of `UIScrollView` when user move to controller and not start scrolling. Like in `UITableView` when user move to tableView vertical indicator shows automatically even if the user not start scrolling. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `flashScrollIndicators`.

**Documentation:**

> Displays the scroll indicators for a short time. This should be done whenever you bring the scroll view to front.

Comment: you should call it when your scrollview would appear on the screen. Like when you are adding it to subview or when you are unhiding it.

Answer (score 2):

Use This Code:

```
self.ScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
```

Make sure you have set `UIScrollViewDelegate` correctly,

```
self.ScrollView.delegate = self
```

Comment: showsVerticalScrollIndicator only works when user is scrolling, afterwards it fades out.

Comment: true is default value for showsVerticalScrollIndicator => this not solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can enable and disable it from storyboard interface.

- Vertical checkbox handles vertical scroll indicator
- Horizontal checkbox handles horizontal scroll indicator

[image]

The same can be set programatically like

```
// For vertical scroll indicator
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true

// For horizontal scroll indicator
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()`

Comment: He is talking about Swift. See the tags